# 10 dBuV EMI noise suppression from 0.8 to 1.8 MHz

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

The 30 V 500 mA power supply I'm working on needs to pass the EMC (EN55015) test. I am attaching the necessary circuit diagram (common mode and differential mode filters) to pass the test according to my research and trial results.

It passes according to the results of the  tests we have done in our own laboratory environment, but I also want to suppress 10 dBuV between 0.7 and 1.8 MHz. (Test result and EMC filter are in the same photo.)

I did a lot of research and experimentation but couldn't find a clear result. I need your advice on this.

[image]

Comment: ~1 MHz is fairly straight forward to simulate if you add the ESR and ESL of your capacitors, equivalent parallell capacitance (EPC?) and ESR of your inductors, leakage inductance of magnetics, stray capacitance of your tracks and simplify the entire DC/DC stage to just pull the same dI/dt in one cycle, you should be able to capture the culprit.

Comment: Is this a conducted emissions (CE) requirement/test?

Comment: Do you have PE (earth) connection? Where's this measurement taken from? L only or N only? Have you tested for both terminals? Also do you have any info about if this is a CM or DM noise?

Comment: This is measurement taken from N. But I measured both L and N. The report is the same on both.From this result I understand that the noise source is common mode. Is this true?@RohatKılıç

Comment: Yes, it is. @SteveSh

Answer (score 1):

Even the rectifier may be a problem.

Use ultra-fast diodes for the diode bridge. Regular "good old rectifiers" are a pit of despair when it comes to EMI. It might sound counter-intuitive: how are "fast" diodes less noisy than good old "slow" diodes? The "slow" diodes still turn off relatively quickly, they just do it too late: they should be switching close to zero voltage to be quiet, and the later they switch, the more voltage there's across the switch - and also the more current. You'll see an improvement just from better diodes - perhaps not in the frequencies you are concerned about, but it will make life better.